# How do I set up filtered out-of-office replies in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, out-of-office

I use Outlook for both work and personal emails and I've been trying to figure out how to set up an out of office reply in Outlook with exceptions.

What I want is to have only my work related/office emails sent the out-of-office reply while any personal emails come through normally (without being sent the autoresponder).

How do I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

See this article:
[How to Set Up an Out of Office Vacation Auto-Reply in Outlook](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_auto_reply.htm)

Comment: hi harrymc, thanx for that link but it states to setup a rule and most of the times rules setup are stored as client only which means they run when ur outlook is on, what i'm looking for is in the OOO assistant how do i exclude external mails from not getting the OOO msg.

Comment: Understood. See in this case my new answer.

Comment: You can setup rules which aren't client specific under the OOO assistant, not be confused with inbox rules

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you wish to have your mail answered for a period when your computer is turned off. I suppose that your mail server is neither a website such as google or yahoo nor an exchange server, since in these cases there is no problem. I also assume that your actual server is pop3.

The only solution I can then think of is to open a gmail account that will:

1. Import contacts from Outlook on your local :
   [Importing contacts by CSV](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8301)
2. Siphon-off all mail from your existing mail supplier:
   [How to Collect Mail from Other POP Accounts in Gmail](http://email.about.com/od/gmailtips/qt/et_collect_pop.htm)
   You may leave your email on your pop3 server, rather than deleting it, so it's still available when you come back.
3. Create filtered auto response in your gmail account:
   [Set up a filtered response in Gmail](http://lifehacker.com/260253/set-up-a-filtered-response-in-gmail)
4. Turn of the siphoning (and the gmail account?) when you come back.

Please also have a look at this good-practices article :
[Use Email Autoresponders with Great Caution](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/08/going-on-holiday-use-email.html).